# How to load Angular 8 components which are not generated with CLI, automatically?

Tags: angular, plugins, angular8

I would like to know if there is an easy way to load Angular 8 components which are not created with CLI on my application without having to add them by myself in :

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    MapComponent,
    PluginComponent,
  ],
```

For example I would like: `PluginTestComponent` to be added in this list.
If there is not a native way, I was thinking to edit the file before the app is launched.

I may not going in the good way too: my final goal is to have a dashboard where I can load components on it, where components can be created by extern people without having access to the src and can just upload their components on a specific folder.

I'm all hear for advices or solutions.

Comment: I think editing the file before launch is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what architecture do you have, but if you have back application you can call this application (java or .net for example) that executes bash command that executes cli (i supposed that you use a unix system).

Angular => back => unix => cli

If your app is full front, via node you can also excuste bash comands that will call cli and create your component dynamically

Node.js => unix => cli